# Is there a URL for a Symfony JSON REST Service WADL?

Tags: php, json, rest, symfony, web-services

I already tried `http://service/?wadl` to get a wadl file, but nothing is returned.

I read there isn't really a standard for wadl files in REST (but there is one for SOAP's WSDL), but I thought maybe it would exist and be web-service framework specific to PHP Symfony.

Is there a default wadl url for pulling a list of function signatures?

Answer (score 1):

There would be, if you create it. Symfony does not define URLs for you, it's just a framework.

A Symfony application is not necessarily a REST API application, or even a Web application. It could be a console application, a message consumer, or anything else. It's not a given that "method signature" should be publicly available via any kind of endpoint.

If you want to an endpoint providing some functionality (say, a WADL endpiont, or a WSDL endpoint, or an anything endpoint), you need to provide it by creating and configuring it.

Some libraries built on top of Symfony like [Api-Platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/) or [NelmioApiDoc](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) can provide some automatic or semi-automatic documentation for an API built on top of symfony, but how to configure each would depend on one actually using these libraries, and what's one's  use-case.

Comment: That's about what I would expect from a PHP library.

The problem is I don't run the platform, I only consume it.  But it's really hard to consume when you only get what someone else tells you is in the system; that's why I was asking if Symfony sets up something like this by default.  

I've used the Java Axis framework and it would generate all of that for you; but PHP being what it is, I would expect that your answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, my answer is correct. If you are on the consumer side of things, neither Symfony nor PHP are to blame, but the developers making the specific application. Not properly documenting an API (or any kind of application) is something that happens all too often, no matter the underlaying technology. Axis framework is a framework specialized in creating web services, so it makes sense it build this out of the box. Symfony is more similar maybe to Java Spring, it's not so specialized, so it assumes the developer will create the app as they wish.